# Is there a JavaScript performance comparison chart available?

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

I'm looking for some data that will show JavaScript performance enhancements by the different browsers over the past few years. Does anyone know of a reliable source for that data? I've found individual graphs showing a snapshot in time using a variety of different tools for performance benchmarks but nothing that shows overall performance over a period of several browser revisions.

Comment: That is like asking if Ford is faster than Dodge.

Comment: How is this question programming related? What kind of script are you writing?

Comment: "Overall performance" is a completely undefined term.  There are hundreds of aspects of performance.  Any measure of overall performance would have to decide on exactly what you were going to measure and count as "overall performance".  As there is no such standard portfolio of tests, I rather doubt you're going to find historical information for such a portfolio for all the browsers over time.

Comment: Okay. Hmm, well I've seen graphs that show JavaScript performance as tested by several benchmarking suites. I've just never seen this data over multiple versions of JavaScript. For example, what I'd like to see is a graph showing V8's performance results in 2005-2011 for the SunSpider benchmark.  Sorry if the original question was too vague. And unfortunately, I don't have yearly snapshots of Chrome/V8 to do this myself.

Comment: And I do think this question is programming related because it's related to the speed of execution of a programming language. But since it's been closed, I suppose others disagree!

Answer (score 1):

The best I know if is http://jsperf.com/browse

It doesn't have historical data, but it does have some great comparisons of “current” browsers.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful. Now, if only I'd kept snapshots of old versions of browsers....